# Call for another ajax from the result one ajax request got

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've header file in which I have search box where user can search for products, this works on ajax request & for getting the info I've livesearch.php file.
Now with the searched products, I want to add 'Add to Cart' button directly. So in fact for every search result there will be one button to add that product in cart. To achieve this, I need to add another ajax request for adding that product into cart.
But nothing's happening while I click on add button. Here's my code.

**Header.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".searchproductbrand").keyup(function()
{
var kw = $(".searchproductbrand").val();
if(kw != '')  
 {
  $.ajax
  ({
     type: "POST",
     url: "livesearch.php",
     data: "kw="+ kw,
     success: function(option)
     {
       $("#livesearch").show();
       $("#livesearch").html(option);
       document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
     }
  });
 }
 else
 {
   $("#livesearch").html("");
   document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
 }
return false;
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(document).live('click', '.buynow', function()
{
var productid = $(this).attr('id');
var quantity = $('.quantity_'+productid).val();
var type= $('.type_'+productid).val();
  $.ajax
  ({
     type: "POST",
     url: "db_addtocart.php",
     data: {'quantity'=quantity, 'type'=type, 'productid'=productid},
     success: function(option)
     {
        this.attr('value','Added');
     }
  });
return false;
});
});
</script>
<?php
<input type="text" id="text" class="searchproductbrand">
?>
```

**livesearch.php**

```
<?php
while(blah blah){
echo "<input type='text' id='quantity' class='quantity_".$row["productid"]."'>".
"&nbsp;<select name='type' class='type_".$row["productid"]."'>".
"<option value='Unit'>Unit</option>";
"</select>";
echo "&nbsp;<input type='button' class='button' id='".$row["productid"]."'
class='buynow' value='Buy Now'>";
}
?>
```

**db_addtocart.php**

This file gets the values of variables & insert into table, nothing sort of important.

What wrong am I doing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `class` attributes in your buttons -> `class='button' id='".$row["productid"]."' class='buynow'`? Combine then into 1 -> `class='button buynow'`.  Also there is no reason to dynamicly load your script code , just add it to the main file.

Comment: Combined them, and what do you mean by no reason to dynamically load my script code? Do you suggest I should add that into header.php file?

Comment: Yes, remove the JavaScript code from ` Livesearch.php` and put it in `Header.php` with the other JavaScript code. Then using @brian's answer with `.live()` instead of `.on()` it should work.

Comment: See the updated code of mine, did as you suggested & it's not working though.

Comment: There is a syntax error with your `data` in your 2nd ajax. Try changing to -> `data: {quantity: quantity, type: type, productid: productid},`

Comment: That's odd because in first ajax, I'm using the same syntax. Let me try with this one though

Comment: Nope that doesn't seem the issue, can't make it work

Comment: In the first one you're only sending 1 parameter so it is valid.  In the second you're sending multiple so the extra commas break syntax so you need to wrap in brackets `{}`. You could also do `data: "quantity="+quantity+"&type="+type+"&productid="+productid,`. Notice the `+"&`, instead of the comma, and you were missing `=` on `type` and `productid`

Comment: Yeah I got it, but that is not working as well, god help me

Comment: Forget Ajax, the thing is I can not click the button, I've tried using window.open with a click, that didn't work as well.

Comment: @Sean Any other help buddy?

Comment: posted an answer with a working code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your js to the code below. I used `.delegate()` instead of `.live()` as according to the manual it is better to use with jQuery 1.4.3+.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".searchproductbrand").keyup(function(){
        var kw = $(".searchproductbrand").val();
        if(kw != ''){
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "livesearch.php",
              data: {kw:kw},
             success: function(option){
               $("#livesearch").show();
               $("#livesearch").html(option);
               $("#livesearch").css("border","1px solid #A5ACB2"); // used $('#...') instead of document.getElementById() AND .css() instead of style.border
             }
          });
        }
        else {
           $("#livesearch").html("").css("border","0px"); // used $('#...') instead of document.getElementById() AND .css() instead of style.border
        }
        return false;
    });
    $(document).delegate('.buynow','click', function(){
        var productid = $(this).attr('id');
        var quantity = $('#quantity_'+productid).val(); // changed from .quantity_ to #quantity - requires change in php code
        var type= $('#type_'+productid).val(); // changed from .type_ to #type - requires change in php code
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db_addtocart.php",
            context: this,  // added as 'this' below was out of scope. see the docs for more info
            data: {quantity:quantity, 
                   type:type, 
                   productid:productid},
            success: function(option){
                   this.value = 'Added'; // changed from this.attr('value','Added');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

This will also require you to update the html created in `livesearch.php` to the following code. Mainly changing from `class=...` to `id=...`

```
<?php
   while(blah blah){
      echo "<input type='text' id='quantity_".$row["productid"]."' />";
      echo "&nbsp;<select name='type' id='type_".$row["productid"]."'>".
           "<option value='Unit'>Unit</option>".
           "</select>";
      echo "&nbsp;<input type='button' class='button buynow' id='".$row["productid"]."' value='Buy Now'>";
}
?>
```

Here is a working JSFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/X8n3d/

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, worked like a charm. Was missing delegate huh? Need to know what it is now.

Comment: Hey I tried to replace the Cart div tag on successful ajax, but that works fine for first request & second onward, only value of button is updated to 'Added' & div is not updating. I've edited your answer with  what I've added into my code. I also added e.preventDefault() as well, but still it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is that your `$(".buynow").click` is bound to the element which are in the dom on load of your page. Any button with `.buynow` added after that has no event.

You need to use jQuery's on() method so the click event works for all elements.

Juste replace `$('.buynow').click(function(e){..})` with `$(document).on('click', '.buynow', function(e){..})` and it should work.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: jquery 1.6.2 is what I'm using

Comment: Ok, on() method has been introduced in jQuery 1.7, you should use live() instead of on(). The live() method has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9, replaced with on(), but it should work the same.

Comment: That's odd. You checked if there's no error in the js console ?

Comment: Yeah I checked & no error is coming, I put it like error: function(xhr, status, error){}

Comment: Forget Ajax, the thing is I can not click the button, I've tried using window.open with a click, that didn't work as well.

Comment: Any other help buddy?